# Run action when c# wpf animation ends

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, doubleanimation

I'm learning wpf and at the same time developing an app with it. I'm having a hard time figuring out how i can run something when a doubleanimation (Or other sorts) is done. For instance:

```
DoubleAnimation myanim = new DoubleAnimation();
myanim.From = 10;
myanim.To = 100;
myanim.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
myview.BeginAnimation(Button.OpacityPropert, myanim);

//Code to do something when animation ends

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

namespace app
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DoubleAnimation widthbutton = new DoubleAnimation();
        widthbutton.From = 55;
        widthbutton.To = 100;
        widthbutton.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
        button1.BeginAnimation(Button.HeightProperty, widthbutton);

        DoubleAnimation widthbutton1 = new DoubleAnimation();
        widthbutton1.From = 155;
        widthbutton1.To = 200;
        widthbutton1.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
        button1.BeginAnimation(Button.WidthProperty, widthbutton1);

        widthbutton.Completed += new EventHandler(myanim_Completed);
    }
    private void myanim_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //your completed action here
        MessageBox.Show("Animation done!");
    }
}
}
```

How is this accomplishable? I have read quite a few other posts about this, but they all explain it using xaml, however i would like to do it using c# code. Thanks!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can attach an event handler to the DoubleAnimation's [Completed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed.aspx) event.

```
myanim.Completed += new EventHandler(myanim_Completed);

private void myanim_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //your completed action here
}
```

Or, if you prefer it inline, you can do

```
 myanim.Completed += (s,e) => 
     {
        //your completed action here
     };
```

Remember to attach the handler before starting the animation otherwise it won't fire.

Comment: It doesn't show any errors in code, but when the animation finishes, nothing happens, see my edit for my complete new code

Comment: You're starting the animation before attaching the handler. You need to attach the handler first before calling `BeginAnimation`.